# How to make server call with axios and pass in parameters?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am a bit new to React... and I use `axios` for server calls... alot. But, this doesn't seem to work.

```js
 getFilteredVendors(loc) {
    console.log(loc)
    const feed = {
      location: loc
    }
    // return axios.get('http://localhost:3001/f_vendor?location=${loc}') this works
    return axios.get('http://localhost:3001/f_vendor', qs.stringify(feed)) // this does not
  }
```

I wondering why? Because I have used `axios` to perform similar and more complex calls than this.

Comment: what you want to pass in header ,data or params ?

Comment: what is you api url

Comment: I'm not passing anything else, it supposed to return a filtered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you don't need the qs.stringify, when you can just pas in params normally. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/axios/axios).

```
getFilteredVendors(loc) {
    console.log(loc)
    const feed = {
      location: loc
    }
    return axios.get('http://localhost:3001/f_vendor', {
    params: {
      location: loc
    }) 
  }

// Or more explicitly

axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'http://localhost:3001/f_vendor',
  data: {
    location: loc
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `params` option for query string param. Example:

```
getFilteredVendors(loc) {
  console.log(loc)
  return axios.get('http://localhost:3001/f_vendor', {
    params: {
      location: loc
    }
  });
}
```